# Which system image to be downloaded while configuring Android Virtual Device (Emulator)?

Tags: android

I am a tyro to Android.

For the tutorials which I am following, he (the author) dictates an ***API Level 18, 19, 21, 22, or 23 image***, and the ***armeabi-v7*** CPU architecture to be downloaded.

Which of the ***2 system images*** depicted in black rectangles, needs to be downloaded?

Secondly, as marked by a red color boundary, why is ***unknown*** reflecting in place of ***Marshmallow***?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The second one is with the google play services. If you are using any services provided by google play services like google analytics, Admob, etc. you will need to download the second one.

Else it is fine to download the first one.